# ¿Cómo colocar formato 12 horas AM-PM en FullCalendar configuración español?

Tags: date, fullcalendar, calendar

Hola estoy tratando de configurar fullcalendar para que me muestre la hora en formato de 12 horas AM- PM, el problema es que si lo dejo con el lenguaje predeterminado que en este caso es el ingles si me muestra la hora como lo quiero pero si lo configuro en español locale: 'es' el formato de hora se pasa a 24 horas, he tratado de realizarlo como se indica a continuacion: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/timeFormat

```
Determines the time-text that will be displayed on each event.

format string, default:

'h:mm'    // like '5:00', for agendaWeek and agendaDay
'h(:mm)t' // like '7p', for all other views
```

pero no lo he conseguido

[image: Calendario]

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciono de esta forma

```
slotLabelFormat:{
             hour: '2-digit',
             minute: '2-digit',
             hour12: true
             },//se visualizara de esta manera 01:00 AM en la columna de horas
eventTimeFormat: {
               hour: '2-digit',
               minute: '2-digit',
               hour12: true
              },//y este código se visualizara de la misma manera pero en 
el titulo del evento creado en fullcalendar
```

Espero te sirva mi respuesta, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes configurar así para te muestre la hora formato 12h

```html
slotLabelFormat:{
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      hour12: true,
      meridiem: 'short',
},
```